# Use Tensor float values in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow in C++, to do prediction using a custom trained model. I can load this model, do prediction for a single image, which returns this tensor type :

```
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,22] values: [0.00760295521 9.67324567e-08 4.19238063e-07]...>
```

I can extract the prediction class by founding the max value indice from this table using another TensorFlow session, as it is done in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_the_c_api).

Now, I try to batch images, always to do predictions and everything is fine, but I have this output Tensor :

```
Tensor<type: float shape: [2,22] values: [0.00760294124 9.6732272e-08 4.19237637e-07]...>
```

Indeed, the shape is now [2,22] as I have 2 images and 22 classes. And now, I would know how I can extract two 22-elements float vectors from this tensor, without using Tensorflow, in classical C++ code. I find some functions that sounds good in the [API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_1a6f5bf51d9c7f2ebf21d56aa8313a8b5f), but I don't understand how to use it.

Does anybody has a little code snippet on how to handle such a case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to do it this way :

```
std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
    Status run_status = session->Run(feed_dict, {"fc2/Softmax"}, {}, &outputs);
    if (!run_status.ok()) {
        cout << "Running model failed: " << run_status;
        return -1;
    }
    for (auto &t : outputs) // access by reference to avoid copying
    {  
        cout << t.DebugString() + "\n";
        tensorflow::TTypes<float, 2>::Tensor scores = t.flat_inner_dims<float>();
        auto dims = scores.dimensions();
        int imgCount = dims[0];
        int classesCount = dims[1];
        for(int i = 0; i<imgCount; i++) {
            float maxVal = scores(i,0);
            int maxIndex = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j<classesCount; j++) {
                float val = scores(i,j);
                if(val > maxVal) {
                    maxVal = val;
                    maxIndex = j;
                }
            }
            cout << "Img" + to_string(i) + " prediction: " + to_string(maxIndex) + ", score: " + to_string(maxVal) + "\n";
        }
    }
```

The function `flat_inner_dims()` allows to retrieve Eigen::Tensor, with the given shape `<float, 2>` that indicates a 2D array of floats. And then, I run over this array.

You can find more informations on how to use Eigen::Tensor [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support#Using_the_Tensor_module).

Hope this could help.